# How to style a PhoneTextBoxs ActionIcon

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Im developing an Windows Phone 8 app and I need to have an PhoneTextBox with an ActionIcon. When the PhoneTextBox is active I style it and I succeeded to style the ActionIcon, but then I can't access the event on the ActionIcon.

Here is my code:

```
<Style TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Custom}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Inverted}" />
        <Setter Property="Hint" Value="{StaticResource Inverted}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Custom}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="HintStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Inverted}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:PhoneTextBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{StaticResource CustomDisableBorder}" KeyTime="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{StaticResource CustomDisableForeground}" KeyTime="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ActionIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="/Images/cancel_light.png" KeyTime="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused" >
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{StaticResource Inverted}" KeyTime="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{StaticResource Custom}" KeyTime="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{StaticResource Custom}" KeyTime="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ActionIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="/Images/cancel_dark.png" KeyTime="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Margin="6,3,0,3"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}"/>
                                <Image Tap="{TemplateBinding ActionIcon}" x:Name="ActionIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="54" Source="/Images/cancel_light.png" Width="54"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tap="{TemplateBinding ActionIcon}"` is wrong, You are binding event to ActionIcon Property of `PhoneTextBox`.

It should be like this if you want the source of image to be TemplateBinding

```
Source="{TemplateBinding ActionIcon}"
```

To Solve your problem, you can use `ActionIconTapped` of `toolkit:PhoneTextBox`

```
 <toolkit:PhoneTextBox ActionIconTapped="PhoneTextBox_ActionIconTapped"/>
```